# Import Function from py file - Strange Error Message

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

Hey brilliant Stack Overflow community, I encountered a strange situation when I tried to import a function from `py file`. It will be much appreciated if you can offer your insights and suggestion!

So, When I create a random function in `FUNK.py` file and use that function in another py script via:

```
from FUNK import some_func
```

I got an ImportError Message. However, if I rename the `FUNK.py` and run the code again, it will work.

That means every time I create a new function in `FUNK.py`, I have to change the file name in order to use another `py script`.

**I am wondering why and how I can use the function without change the file name again and again?**

[image]

Comment: paste your code instead of image

Comment: It looks like it's complaining about line 13 of main.py - `an_apple?`. Can you show us a chunk of your code near there?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Omada Sorry for the late reply! The updated question is what I actually encountered. I would love to hear your advice!

Comment: @vae Is this only happening in the interactive python console? Or does it happening when you run a single script as well? I wouldn't expect importing the same file over/over after modifying it to work well without closing out python.

Comment: @Omada it appears both in the console and the single script. Every time I add a new function in the script ( the FUNK.py), I have to rename it to a file before I import it into another script. It is pretty strange.